# Boundedness in locally convex space

Tags: metric-spaces, locally-convex-spaces

Consider a vector space $X$ equipped with a separating countable family of seminorms $(p_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$. I'm told that the boundedness of a set in $X$ with respect to each one of the seminorms simultaneously is a stronger assumption than boundedness with respect to the metric defined by $d(x,y) = \Sigma \frac{1}{2^i}\min(1,p_i(x-y))$.
So first thing I say to myself well this is a bit odd since then we have to choose which definition to use for boundedness. But then I realised that every metrisable locally convex space is bounded for that metric, unless I've missed something, isn't it ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps an example may help?

$X=\ell^\infty({\Bbb N})$. Let $(e_k)_{k\geq 1}$ be the canconical base. Then the family of semi-norms:
$$ p_k(x)= |\langle e_k,x\rangle|, \ \ k\geq 1$$
gives rise to the weak topology on $X$. A sequence (of sequences) $\xi_n\in X$ goes to zero iff each coordinate goes to zero. A ball for the metric you wrote is very 'big', i.e. contains cylinder sets with constraints only on finitely many coordinates. Now, on the other hand if you look at a subset where each $p_k$ is bounded then that will not be open in the weak topology. If you impose even that each $p_k(x)<1$ then you will be looking at the unit ball in $X$ (which again is not open in the weak topology).

Comment: This is very late. But may I ask, if the metric in the OP were to change to $d(x,y)=\sum_i \frac{1}{2^i}\frac{p_i(x-y)}{1+p_i(x-y)}$, as how it's usually done, the two "boundedness" would be equivalent? Or is it still no?

Comment: @user760 The metric you describe is equivalent to the one given by the OP and for both metrics the space has finite diameter. Being bounded is not really an issue. The topology is. With the given metric (yours or that of the OP) the topology is the same as the weak topology that I described. And this you cannot obtain by asking for all semi-norms to be simultaneously bounded (whether uniformly or not).
Hope this makes sense to you...

Comment: I just realized, $0\leq \frac{1}{2^i}\frac{p_i(x-y)}{1+p_i(x-y)}\leq \frac{1}{2^i}$, and the right hand side can be approached with $p_i\to \infty$. So the metric being bounded doesn't imply any of $p_i$ being bounded. Same is true for the OP's metric. Thanks a lot